# Windows Service Webbrowser object invalid cast exception error

Tags: c#, browser, .net

I'm having a bit of trouble with a Windows Service webbrowser object. It's attempting to load in values of username and password to a site but keeps failing and throwing the following error:

`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLDocument2.GetLocation()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_Document()
   at MyWindowsService.MyDataProcessor.login()`

The code that I'm using to make this call is:

```
MyWebBrowser.Document.All["Login"].SetAttribute("Value", username);
            MyWebBrowser.Document.All["Password"].SetAttribute("Value", password);
            MyWebBrowser.Document.All["submit"].InvokeMember("Click");
```

Any ideas as to why it keeps failing? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So I think I've found out what the problem is. There's a bug in the WebBrowser object that prevents the DocumentCompleted from firing when it's not visible which is what a Windows Service is all about. (Here's a link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259935)

How do I go about correcting this? I'd love to continue to use the WebBrowser object so I don't have to rewrite everything but don't know how to make it visible in a Windows Service. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solves the problem, but you can check InvokeRequired property on the current object, or WebBrowser.InvokeRequired, and use something like MethodInvoker to call your function or a helper function to access WebBrowser.Document.

http://www.megasolutions.net/cSharp/(WebBrowser_Document-==-null)-throws-InvalidCastException-43126.aspx

Comment: Im not sure it Sam saw Axl:s answer, but the Invoke-thing seems to be the answer. I just had the same problem and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315938/webbrowser-document-cast-not-valid/318538#318538 . That solved my problem =)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using SHDocVW.WebBrowserClass. I got an InvalidCastException when I tried to access Document.all from an instance of SHDocVW.WebBrowserClass (from the main thread) and I was able to fix it by casting to IHTMLDocument2 instead of HTMLDocument. This took me a long time to figure out because casting to HTMLDocument works most of the time.

```
SHDocVW.WebBrowserClass Explorer = [instance of IE];
((IHTMLDocument2)Explorer.Document).all  // works all the time
((HTMLDocument)Explorer.Document).all    // works some times
```

I hope this helps someone.