# Specified cast is not valid - HTMLDocument

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use this snippet to test of an element has a specific text.

```
HtmlDocument element = webBrowser2.Document;

if (element.GetElementById("gbqfsa").InnerText == "Google Search")
{
     HasSucceeded = 1;
}
return HasSucceeded;
```

However the first line throws the exception "Specified cast is not valid."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `webBrowser2`?

Comment: A webBrowser control.

Comment: Could this be my problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566337/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you are using the wrong HtmlDocument class?  WebBrowser.Document is of the type:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument
```

But I noticed that there is also another possible namespace:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlDocument
```

I would check to make sure the namespace you included was `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`

Comment: if I try to include `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` in addition to the `System.Windows.Form` namespace I'm already using, I get an error. "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' is a type not a namespace."

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem when return HtmlDocument as property from my custom user control. (Which embedded WebBrowser control)

Cause of error because access document from other thread.

```
/// <summary>
/// Error version '
/// </summary>
public HtmlDocument Document
{
    get
    {
        // Throw error 'Specified cast is not valid'
        return this.webBrowserMain.Document; 
    }
}
```

But I don't known why error is not 'CrossThread Operation access ...' but next code solved my problem

```
/// <summary>
/// Fixed version
/// </summary>
delegate HtmlDocument DlgGetDocumentFunc();
public HtmlDocument GetDocument()
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        return (HtmlDocument)this.webBrowserMain.Invoke(new DlgGetDocumentFunc(GetDocument), new object[] { });
    }
    else
    {
        return this.webBrowserMain.Document;
    }
}
```